# Why geometrical symmetry breaks in planetary motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, symmetry, orbital-motion, planets

We all know a planet's orbit around a star (like our earth and sun) is an ellipse and not a circle and the sun locates in one of the focal points of the ellipse. When textbooks formulate this motion, solve the equations and prove the orbit is elliptical, they suppose an isolated sun and earth system (ignoring gravitational forces from other planets/stars).

On the other hand, we know the Newton gravitational force is symmetrical around a star (depends only on $r$, the distance between the star and planet). So, I expect to have an orbit with **symmetrical geometry** (i.e. a circle). Could somebody explain conceptually (no maths), why this symmetry breaks and we end up with an elliptical orbit instead of a circular?

Secondly, as we know an ellipse has 2 focal points, so why the star (for instance our sun) sits in one of the focal points and not the other one (what's special about this focal point as opposed to the other).

Comment: Perhaps it would help your understanding if you consider the fact that a circle is an ellipse with its foci coincident.  While a circular orbit is possible in theory, there are a lot more elliptical possibilities than the single circular one.  So it's just not observed in our solar system at least.

Comment: A circle doesn't have spherical symmetry.

Comment: [Orbits are circles in 4 dimensions](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/planets_in_the_4th_dimension/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, that’s not so much an example of symmetry breaking as a misunderstanding of how symmetry works.

If I may lightly rephrase, your claim is that because the gravitational force between two bodies depends only on the distance between them, the subsequent *motion* of those bodies should be such that the distance between them is constant.

But you *also* intuitively know that if you hold them a fixed distance apart and release them from rest, they will fall towards each other, so the distance between them is *not* constant.

Ultimately, the thing to understand is that a symmetry of the equations of motion - which in this case means the rotational symmetry of the gravitational force - does not imply that the *solutions* to those equations possess the same symmetry. Rather, it implies that the *set of all solutions* has that symmetry.

More concretely, if you take an orbit and rotate it, you don’t get the same orbit back - but you **do** get another possible orbit. This is what symmetry means in dynamical systems.

——

As for your second question, it’s not that you have elliptical motion and then some influence places the gravitational center at one focus or the other. Instead, you start with the gravitational center at some fixed point, and then based on the initial conditions (initial position and velocity of the satellite) there is precisely one ellipse which fits those initial conditions and has the gravitational center at one of its foci. If you imagine the gravitational center at the other focus, then the orbit will no longer “fit” those initial conditions.